# Check a Tree View CheckBox using pywinauto 0.5.4

Tags: checkbox, treeview, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto 0.5.4, my problem is I cannot check, the checkbox(s) the are in a treeview.
Here's the code I'm trying out:

```
>>> from pywinauto import application
>>> app=application.Application()
>>> app.Start("C:\Program Files\ValiFrame.exe")
>>> RxApp= app['N5990A Test Automation Software Platform']
>>> RxApp[u'TreeView'].GetItem([u'PCI Express   -   3.0, Add-In Card'
, u'Receiver', u'5.0 GT/s', u'Lane0', u'Compliance Test']).Check()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_treeview_element' object has no attribute 'Check'
```

I tried using Click(), but it just highlights the text next to the checkbox.

Here's an image showing the application and the checkbox I want to check. [Application checkboxs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aod7a.jpg)
I've been using SWAPY 0.4.8 to help me identify the control elements, but there's doesn't seem to be a control identifier listed. [SWAPY results screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGoGN.jpg)

Is there a way to identify the actual checkbox control and control attribute that actually checkmarks the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the check boxes using `Click(where='check')`. More detailed docs are here: [class _treeview_element](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.controls.common_controls.html#pywinauto.controls.common_controls._treeview_element).

These methods might be useful for your needs:

> Click(button='left', double=False, where='text', pressed='') Click on
>   the treeview item
>
> where can be any one of “text”, “icon”, “button”, “check” defaults to
>   “text”
>
> ClickInput(button='left', double=False, wheel_dist=0, where='text',
>   pressed='') Click on the treeview item
>
> where can be any one of “text”, “icon”, “button”, “check” defaults to
>   “text”
>
> IsChecked() Return whether the TreeView item is checked or not

Comment: Vasily, thank you for response. I tried Click(where='check'), but it just highlights the text , instead of the checkbox.  When I manually click on the checkbox then use IsChecked(), it returns True.  If I'm able to correctly determine the state of this item, then I'm hoping there's also a way to set the state of this item.

Comment: Try `ClickInput(where='check')`. TreeView is very specific control so the wrapper interface is a little unusual in compare with others.

Comment: Is it working with `ClickInput(where='check')`? If no, I want to look at this in more details.